# How can I generate and Insert the generated ID into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert the generated ID into Pin table in the AppID column of the Pin table and I am finding it difficult.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $dbhost="localhost";
  $dbusr="root";
  $dbpass="gandepuun";
  $database="portal";

  mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusr,$dbpass, $database);
  mysql_select_db($database) or die("database not connected");

  $num = rand(98564654, 415231564); 
  
  If(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $ID =$_POST['ID'];
    if($npin=='Pin') {
      $sql="INSERT INTO pin('AppID') VALUES($num) WHERE $npin==AppID";
      if($sql=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        header("location:profile.php");
      }
    }
  }                 
?>
```

The pin table has ID, Pin and AppID as column heads

Comment: Answer 1: Notice: Undefined index: AppID in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\Compet_loginID.php on line 11

Comment: some alignment changes for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql **update**

```
$sql="Update pin set AppID='$num' WHERE ".$npin."='AppID'";
```

Comment: Change  WHERE ".$npin."='AppID'" or try this query @Igbeh Emmanuel

Comment: Undefined index: appid in C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\Compet_loginID.php on line 11

Comment: use AppID in ' ' like that :- 'AppID'